# Drag & Drop HTML 5 jQuery: e.dataTransfer.setData() with JSON

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

Here it is my dragstart:

```
dragstart: function(e) {
    $(this).css('opacity', '0.5');
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    e.dataTransfer.setData('application/json', {
        id: $(this).attr('id'),
        header: $('header', this).text()
    });
},
```

I would like to pass some informations such id and text. My drop is:

```
drop: function(e) {
    var data = e.dataTransfer.getData('application/json');
    alert(data);
    $(this).attr('id', data.id);
    $('header', this).text(data.header);
},
```

But data is undefined, I can't access to my data. Is it the right way?

Thank's!

Comment: Could it be related to this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640234/jquery-ui-draggable-droppable-datatransfer-is-undefined

Answer (score 13):

in drag start

```
var testjson = {name:"asd",tall:123};
e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain",JSON.stringify(testjson));
e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "copy";
```

in drop

```
var data = e.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
console.log(JSON.parse(data));
```

and u will get

```
Object {name: "asd", tall: 123}
```

in console.log

Comment: This however allows the user to drop the json-string on any <input/>-Element by default, which might not be intended.

Comment: It would be more convenient if there was a way to pass the actual json object. It's a shame that you have to stringify it.

Answer (score -1):

If you include an effectAllowed in your dragstart function, such as:

```
e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
```

Then it is my understanding that you need to define an equivalent dropEffect in the drop function  :

```
e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
```