# IE 9+ JQuery drag & drop for div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function OnDragStartElement(e) {
    //this.style.opacity = '0.4';           
    srcElementParent = this;
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    var elementCount = formElements.length > 0 ? Math.max.apply(Math, formElements.map(function (o) { return o.ID; })) : 0;     

    var elementText = $(this).children()[0].innerHTML;      
    var elementType = $($(this).children()[1])[0].value;
    var elementID = (elementCount + 1);
    var draggedElement = elementText + ': ' + elementText + elementID
    //debugger;
    e.dataTransfer.setData("dragedElement", draggedElement);
    e.dataTransfer.setData('draggedElementType', elementType);
    e.dataTransfer.setData('draggedElementID', elementID);
    isElementNotPlaced = true;
    isdragDivElement = false;
}
```

An error is thrown:

> Unexpected call to method or property access.

The error I see is on the line:

```
e.dataTransfer.setData("dragedElement", draggedElement);
```

The same code works fine on Chrome & Firefox.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Error message : Unexpected call to method or property access.

Comment: Aha, see [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer#Browser_compatibility) for  `dataTransfer`

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? Remember that IE9 has been deprecated (as well as 8 and 10) since last year.

Comment: Fix formatting, remove unrelated HTML tag.

Answer (score 1):

Refere this link.

[Drag & Drop HTML 5 jQuery: e.dataTransfer.setData() with JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533585/drag-drop-html-5-jquery-e-datatransfer-setdata-with-json)

no need to set data for each

```
e.dataTransfer.setData("dragedElement", draggedElement);
e.dataTransfer.setData('draggedElementType', elementType);
e.dataTransfer.setData('draggedElementID', elementID);
```

instead of this we can pass single json object as text.

Comment: ... and that will cause the error message to go away in IE9?