# difference between event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files and event.dataTransfer.files in html 5

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

What is the difference between

```
event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files
```

and

```
event.dataTransfer.files
```

???

Because in drag and drop , second code does not work and it is undefined and i had to use first code because it works !

Answer (score 42, accepted):

jQuery does not pass the browser event object to you, it passes the [jQuery event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/). You can access the original untouched event object by the `.originalEvent` property in the jQuery event object. Then you can proceed as normal.

So in code:

jQuery event model:

```
$(document).on("drop dragend dragstart dragenter dragleave drag dragover", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.type === "drop") {
        alert(event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files);
    }
});
```

W3C event model:

```
function preventDefault(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}

function alertFiles(event) {
    alert(event.dataTransfer.files);
}
document.addEventListener("dragstart", preventDefault, false);
document.addEventListener("dragenter", preventDefault, false);
document.addEventListener("dragleave", preventDefault, false);
document.addEventListener("drag", preventDefault, false);
document.addEventListener("dragend", preventDefault, false);
document.addEventListener("dragover", preventDefault, false);
document.addEventListener("drop", preventDefault, false);
document.addEventListener("drop", alertFiles, false);
```

Comment: Thank u so much for replay ! i got it ;)  ... i want to vote your answer but it says "Vote Up requires 15 reputation" why ?!  :(

Comment: @user1574766 well, one needs 15 reputation before they can start upvoting answers. You currently have 11 reputation.

Comment: @peyman gilmour you're expected to accept the answer if it helped you (no restrictions for this action)

Comment: I was having the exact problem and while I managed to find something on the internet about the .originalEvent, this finally explained it for me. Much kudos!